Memory address too big
When I run the following program to see the address of a variable :
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int i = 154;

   printf("%p",&i);
   return 0;
}

I get 0x7fff578bdfac (in decimal 140734662172588) and my computer's RAM is only 32GB.
Why so ?

Have you ever heard of virtual memory?

There’s a lot of information in those answers, @teapot418, but discerning the answer to this question from that one would be hard, IMO.  At least, it would be hard until you have understood it all. It’s a good reference for more information; it’s not so good as “the answer” to this question.

Virtual memory is not actually the answer. With either virtual or physical addressing, there is no requirement that the numbers used for addressing bytes in memory be a numbering of the bytes starting from zero. For example, a computer might use physical bus addresses 0-1023 for interacting with I/O devices and bus addresses 1024-8191 for accessing memory. OP’s program has an address 0x7fff578bdfac because that address was configured for it, and that is common and easy with virtual memory, but it could have been done with physical memory too.

I agree. All the answers are talking about virtual memory, as if the physical memory is always contiguously mapped and zero based, which is not true. Physical RAM can be very well "connected" to system address spaces which are somewhere in the middle or end of the range. Different DIMMs can be "connected" at discontinuous ranges. They can even partitioned into regions at discontinuous ranges.

You are printing a virtual address (and there’s no reasonable way to find the corresponding physical address).  Virtual addresses are not constrained to 0..maximum-memory.

Even physical addresses are not constrained. The RAM can physically reside somewhere in the middle of the system address space

I rather suspected that physical memory addresses are not necessarily in the range 0..maximum-memory, but I wasn't sure, so I wrote a minimal but accurate answer ("virtual addresses are not constrained …").  The ranges for physical addresses are inherently dependent on processor type (at least at the generic family level — Intel vs ARM vs SPARC vs PPC vs …) and probably on the specific hardware in the machine being looked at, so delving into those details is probably beyond what's necessary to answer this question.  This points out that the OP needs to study "physical vs virtual memory".

Most present-day OSes use virtual memory. Every process receives its own address space, covering a large portion of the possible pointer range (32, 48 or 64 bits).
See for example this question for more details.

In modern operating systems, user processes don't use physical memory addresses but virtual addressing.
The OS will map a piece of physical memory to a process and give it a (somewhat arbitrary) starting address.  So in a 64-bit OS, the process can in theory have any value in the range of 64-bit values.
What most OSs do these days is, in a given process's address space, addresses with the high bit cleared are reserved for user accessible memory, while addresses with the high bit set are reserved for kernel memory.
